# prevent special characters in input fields using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to block all special characters in the input fields using jquery, any suggestion in doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also check the more specific [alphanumeric plugin](http://itgroup.com.ph/alphanumeric/)

Example:

```
$('.sample1').alphanumeric();
```

Allows alphabet and numeric characters

Comment: Thanks DrDro,this is very much helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Simple function to allow alpha only char :

```
function AlphaNumericOnly(e,isAlphaonly)
{
   // copyright 1999 Idocs, Inc. http://www.idocs.com
   var key = [e.keyCode||e.which];

   var keychar = String.fromCharCode([e.keyCode||e.which]);
   keychar = keychar.toLowerCase();

   if(isAlphaonly=='true')
         checkString="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   else 
         checkString="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

   if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || 
         (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27) )
        return true;
   else if (((checkString).indexOf(keychar) > -1))
        return true;
   else
        return false;
}
```