# JavaScript or Jquery code to prevent special chars on number pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input, special-characters

In my project, I have to prevent the user form entering the following chars in the text box:
`!@#$%^&*()`. So How to achieve this with JavaScript/Jquery? I am using it in asp.net web application.

Comment: I might suggest that in this case, like many but not all validation cases, it may be better to have a set of allowed characters rather than a set of prohibited ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following library : [jQuery plugin validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/)

And add a custom method as demoed here [Phone US](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) and/or jQuery [validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin on client side. However you should validate your stuff also on server side.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="keys">
    <script>
    var forbidden = /[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)]/g;
    var field = document.getElementById('keys');

    field.addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
        var val = field.value;
        if (forbidden.test(val)) {
            field.value = val.replace(forbidden, "");
        }
    }, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: This cleans illegal characters also when copy+pasting, while keydown doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this a code for each character.

```
$('input:text').keydown(function(e){
  if(e.shiftKey && (e.keyCode == 192 || e.keyCode == 49 || 
    e.keyCode == 222 || e.keyCode == 52 || e.keyCode == 53 || 
    e.keyCode == 54 || e.keyCode == 55 || e.keyCode == 56 || 
    e.keyCode == 57 || e.keyCode == 48)){
      return false;
  }
})
```

You could try [how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

Oh yes and validate your input on the server side as well