# only allow English characters and numbers for text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, validation, alphanumeric

Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thisizmonster/DveuB/

How can I change this so that the input only allows the characters A-Z, a-z, 0-9 while typing, without using a regular expression?

Comment: The method you want is called `keypress`, not `keyPress`.

Comment: Why without regEx? This would be really easy with regEx!

Comment: You'd still need add a special case for control chars.

Comment: Because I don't know regEx! Can you do it for me?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery

Comment: "while typing" So mouse copy&paste or other types of non-keyboard input are okay?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Assuming you also want to accept spaces:

```
$("#user").keypress(function(event){
    var ew = event.which;
    if(ew == 32)
        return true;
    if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
        return true;
    if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
        return true;
    if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
        return true;
    return false;
});
```

If you don't want to accept spaces then remove the `if(ew == 32) return true;`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/DveuB/2/)

Comment: I just entered a é (alt-e-e) in your text box on OSX, it does stop µ though. Neither Safari nor Firefox trigger keypress events for composed characters on OSX.

Comment: @Gerelt See my updated post for a new link to prevent what 'mu is too short' is talking about!

Comment: the bad thing is that the user is able to paste a mal-formatted string

Comment: @Mir for `Backspace` add `if (ew == 8) return true;`

Comment: Could someone also give an idea on how to avoid or restrict characters like ý, Ý â, ê, î, ô, û etc from typing or pasting into the input field?

Answer (score 10):

```html
<input type="text" id="firstName"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)" />
```

The ASCII Character Set : https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp

Comment: Note that this wouldn't stop the user from copying & pasting unwanted characters into the input field.

Comment: you can change "onkeypress" to "onblur".

Answer (score 7):

All other answers are fine **but** don't prevent copy and paste non-English characters.

‌Bellow code works for both (**key press** and **copy-paste**):

```
<input type="text" name="text" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^A-Za-z\s]/g,'');">
```

Comment: I wish I understood regex, honestly I wish regex went away replaced with something easier to create. Oh great RegEx master, how do I add 0-9 to this?

Comment: @EricWeintraub, you can use this /[^0-9A-Za-z\s]/g

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/DveuB/1/

Then it's only 0-9, a-z and A-Z

```
$(function(){
    $("#user").keypress(function(event){
        if ((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || // 0-9
            (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || // A-Z
            (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122))  // a-z
            alert("0-9, a-z or A-Z");
    });
});
```

**Update:** http://jsfiddle.net/DveuB/4/
To prevent what @mu is talking about:

```
$("#user").keyup(function(event){
    if (event.altKey == false && event.ctrlKey == false)
        if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57 && event.shiftKey== false) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) ||
            (event.keyCode >= 97 && event.keyCode <= 122))
            alert("0-9, a-z or A-Z");
});
```

Comment: I can get a composed character (such as é which is built from alt-e-e) past that on OSX in both Safari and Firefox, those characters don't seem to trigger keypress events.

Comment: if(event.keyCode == 8) return true;

Comment: answer missed out. you should test repeat "point" (.) you can enter more than one.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.clsAlphaNoOnly').keypress(function (e) {  // Accept only alpha numerics, no special characters 
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }); 
})
</script>

<body>

<input class='clsAlphaNoOnly' type='text'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this function.

By modifying RegExp you can get rid of any characters you don't like personally.

```
$(function(){
    $("#user").bind('keypress',function(e){
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) return true;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you have to write some if statements or something like that, that takes the keycode and validates it against some numbers that represent other keycodes:

for example:

`if(keycode < 80)
  return false;`

Comment: This code will prevent you from using backspace. You need to handle control chars and always allow them.

Comment: This was just for the example. Of course you need to figure out which codes you want to allow (like backspace, arrows, etc.) and which codes you want to ignore.

Comment: This has the same problem as 321X's on OSX.