# Allow only numbers and letters to input string

Tags: javascript, html, regex, validation, input

I'm trying to avoid input of any marks except numbers and letters with input string on my `page.php`:

```
<input type="text" id="input">
```

From this answer [only allow English characters and numbers for text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144167/only-allow-english-characters-and-numbers-for-text-input) `<input type="text" id="input" class="clsAlphaNoOnly">` :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.clsAlphaNoOnly').keypress(function (e) {  // Accept only alpha numerics, no special characters 
        var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
        var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
        if (regex.test(str)) {
            return true;
        }

        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }); 
})
```

or this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#input").keypress(function(event){
        var ew = event.which;
        if(ew == 32)
            return true;
        if(48 <= ew && ew <= 57)
            return true;
        if(65 <= ew && ew <= 90)
            return true;
        if(97 <= ew && ew <= 122)
            return true;
        return false;
    });
});
```

in both cases string is clear, but I'm using two types of input with button click  `$("#btn").click(function()` to process input and `$(document).keypress(function(e)` with hit on enter key on keyboard for same input. By some reason if I include this methods to avoid extra marks in string, pressing on enter key does not allows to input inserted value.

This way works fine:

```
<input type="text" id="input"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)" />
```

but I want avoid extra code with `html` in `page.php`. I'm trying to figure out, what causes blocking of entering for inserted value with given methods

Comment: well enter is key 13 and you are not allowing it and code can be bypassed with paste.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would tell you may miss event parameter ?

Without jQuery works like this for me in 3 browsers:

```js
function clsAlphaNoOnly (e) {  // Accept only alpha numerics, no special characters 
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (regex.test(str)) {
        return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
function clsAlphaNoOnly2 () {  // Accept only alpha numerics, no special characters 
    return clsAlphaNoOnly (this.event); // window.event
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onkeypress="clsAlphaNoOnly(event)" onpaste="return false;">
<input type="text" id="input" onkeypress="clsAlphaNoOnly2()" onpaste="return false;">
```

Comment: Or check console your log for errors, btw pattern does not exist in IE.

Comment: There should be some onpaste fix, but for simplicity blocked it according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226574/disable-pasting-text-into-html-form#1723838

Answer (score 5):

One way of validation is using `pattern` attribute on `input` element

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation#Validating_against_a_regular_expression

In your case:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]*">
```

Comment: Hello, sure this way good with "required" as alert for incorrect text, but I  have to clean typed text for input

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want to use the Regex method as the comments bellow advice you, then you can use this simple code :

```js
document.querySelector("input#testInput").addEventListener("input", function(){
  const allowedCharacters="0123456789azertyuiopqsdfghjklmwxcvbnAZERTYUIOPQSDFGHJKLMWXCVBNzáàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ "; // You can add any other character in the same way
  
  this.value = this.value.split('').filter(char => allowedCharacters.includes(char)).join('')
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="testInput">
```

Comment: Hey, how can I use your example with regex? the example above use regex but needs a function onkeypress inside input...

Comment: Hey @Sophie, actually you don't need my example to validate a simple regex.

Comment: Hello again @Sophie, I have made this codepen for your to make get your a better solution for your problem https://codepen.io/adnane-ar/pen/gOGdvdY

Comment: Hey @Adnane I dont want to validate a phone number, I want to use this regex: "[A-Za-záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ ]" with the same model as your code, using addEventListener

Comment: Hi @Sophie, then why not just add/append your `záàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñÁÀÂÃÉÈÍÏÓÔÕÖÚÇÑ` to the `allowedCharacters` string and that would do it.

Comment: Hey adnane, using this not permit the accents =/ could you help me out?

Comment: @Sophie, sure can you please provide me with your code just so I could read it and see where to do the magic!

Comment: Hey Adnane, heres the pen https://codepen.io/sophiehf35/pen/NWaEWbr

Comment: @Sophie, https://paste.pics/FM7RV did you try to do it that way?

Comment: Dam.. so the point is just insert in the end... haha thanks

Comment: @Sophie, you're welcome, have a great day!

Comment: you too hehe thank you soo much for your attenction =]

Comment: @Sophie, I inviter you to take a look at the modern version. I have edited the current answer to a perfect example for you!

Comment: nice your code is shorter then mine :O

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240970/discussion-between-sophie-and-adnane-ar).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of javascript you could use a [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#pattern) along with [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#required). `pattern` will allow you to specify a required pattern for the input, and `required` will make the input required. Both must `evaluate` to `true` in order for the form to submit.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" id="input" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" required> 
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: FYI, `pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"` = `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` as the latter is transated into a `^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$` pattern.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it.

Comment: @Get Off My Lawn Hello, yes I've missed to note that I  have to clean typed text for input, because pattern would be useful only for  "required" alert, but will allow marks to string in textbox

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Input Way :**

1- Simple HTML5 Input

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]*">
```

2- Inline Function

```
<input type="text" id="input"  onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 65 && event.charCode <= 90) || (event.charCode >= 97 && event.charCode <= 122) || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)" />
```

---

---

**Jquery Way :**

```
$('#ID').on('keypress', function (e) { var code = ('charCode' in e) ? e.charCode : e.keyCode; if (!(code > 47 && code < 58) && !(code > 64 && code < 91) && !(code > 96 && code < 123)) {e.preventDefault();}});
```

---

---

**Javascript Function :**

```
function allowAlphaNumericSpace(e) {
  var code = ('charCode' in e) ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
  if ( !(code > 47 && code < 58) && !(code > 64 && code < 91) && !(code > 96 && code < 123)) { e.preventDefault();}};

<input type="text" onkeypress="allowAlphaNumeric(event)" />
```