# How can I validate if the characters in a text input are english characters?

Tags: javascript, validation, input

Example on focus out I want to check if the input has any characters that are not in english.
Is this possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe duplicate of [only-allow-english-characters-and-numbers-for-text-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144167/only-allow-english-characters-and-numbers-for-text-input)

Comment: What do you mean by `english characters`? only allow a-z, A-Z?

Comment: `if(inputElement.value.match(/^[a-z0-9_ ]+$/i)){ /* it's English */ }`. Add any special characters you need at the end of those square brackets, after the white space.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping this very simple.

```js
document.getElementById('test').onkeyup = function(){
  if(this.value.match(/^[a-z0-9_.,'"!?;:& ]+$/i)){
    console.log('English'); 
  }
  else{
    console.log('Not English');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='test' value='' />
```