# Javascript numeric form validation, numeric characters only issue

Tags: javascript

I have started a new JavaScript task, which tells me to validate a form with a field and a button. Whenever I type in a random number, an alert box should appear with an answer 'The number is bigger/smaller than 10'. So far so good-I did that part of the task.
The problem appears, when I type in the letter-the alert box appears anyway.
How could this be fixed?

Code looks like this:

```
function validate(){
    x=document.myForm
    txt=x.myInput.value
    if (txt>=10)

    {
        alert("Number is bigger than 10")
        return true

    }

    else

    {
        alert("Number is smaller than 10")
        return false
    }
```

}

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return validate()">
Enter a number: 
<input type="text" name="myInput" size="20">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery

Comment: should the text box allow only int values >= 10

Comment: There should be 1000 links to tell you how to handle this. Do your part to make the web not junk !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could add one more else if statement to your code like below:

x=document.myForm.myInput.value;

```
else if(isNaN(x))

    {
        alert("Number cant be alphabet")
        return false
    }
```

**Below is the Full Script**

```
<script>
            function validate(){
    x=document.myForm.myInput.value;

    if (x >=10)

    {
        alert("Number is bigger than 10")
        return true

    }

    else if(isNaN(x))

    {
        alert("Number cant be alphabet")
        return false
    }
    else

    {
        alert("Number is smaller than 10")
        return false
    }

}
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use parseInt.

```
txt = parseInt(x.myInput.value,10);
```