# how to validate not to allow Chinese characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

One of my SQL like statement is breaking when user enters Chinese characters. I did some research and couldn't find any.

Is there any code available like a plugin or javascript function to validate and allow only english alphanumeric and allow special symbols.

If i validate Chinese characters there can be other languages right , so i thought to allow only english characters with all combination of numbers and symbols.

any direction or input will be appreciated thanks

I tried something like this but this allows only alphanumeric

```
/[^a-zA-Z 0-9]+/g
```

Comment: Here you go; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery

Comment: What database server are you using and how is it breaking? It could be that you just need to change the collation on your database.

Comment: @nullability somewhere it is breaking , it need to debug more on that but thought i will ask here for suggestoins

Comment: @nullability you are right , its mysql

Answer (score 8):

How about UTF8 encoding the text rather than ban languages?