# How can I validate the text-box for restricting user to input for | character

Tags: javascript, validation, restriction

I have placed one text area and I want to put restriction on it ..

Only special characters | should not be allowed to input in text area because I'm using | character in split function.

Comment: Use regex or catch the keycode for '|' character.

Answer (score 0):

Call this javascript function at your textbox

```
function isSpclChar(){
var iChars = "|";
if(document.qfrm.q.value.indexOf(iChars) != -1) {

 alert ("This special character is not allowed.");
 return false;
```

}

}

if you don't want to allow special charaters in textbox

then use

```
 var iChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?";
```

Answer (score 0):

check this link first

[how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

you need to do the opposite here, just look to match for '|'

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    var patt=/|/g;
    var result=patt.test( key ) ;
    if (!result) {
       event.preventDefault();
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

`Script`:

```
function alpha(e) {
  var k = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
  return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
}
```

`HTML` :

```
<input type="text" id="id" onkeypress="return alpha(event);" />
```