# jQuery disable letters in input forms

Tags: jquery, html

How to disable letters on dynamcaly created HTML input forms with jQuery? 
I can make this for input forms which alerady exist but cant make for dynamicaly created new forms.

Comment: But... Why can't you?

Comment: Use event delegation or rebind the handlers after creating the new forms.

Comment: try don't say you cant without trying...

Comment: I tried but I could not because I'm still learning jQuery and I need this, can you send me some example code I would be grateful?

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: `type="number"` in the `input` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery v1.7, "live" is deprecated.  You should use "on" for event delegation. Ex:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
      // do something
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
```

A working example including the regex you need can be found at http://jsfiddle.net/5XXJR/

Comment: I use jquery 1.10.1 and put this in head of my site and cant make to work, what should i do?

Comment: Try waiting until the DOM has loaded to execute your code, see updated example above:

Answer (score 7):

You need simply to use the "live" function of Jquery, Just as following:

```
$('input').live('keypress', function(key) {
    if(key.charCode < 48 || key.charCode > 57) return false;
});
```

This is applied on all inputs in the file, either generated on page load or on the fly, You can replace it with a class name to handle only this group of inputs if you have other inputs in the file.

Here you are a full example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/8575/

Comment: Thanks for the code, but i put that code in head of my page and won't work, why?

Comment: The reason shouldn't be but names problem, Either you share with us the related parts of the code, or you check the names and debug your code well.

Comment: .live() is deprecated, use .on() instead

Comment: thank you for the answer, but this prevent functions like delete, backspace paste. is there way to enable those functions an prevent trying letters an special characters, Thanks

Comment: @SunethKalhera: For sure you can exclude any character. You can refer to the list of ASCII control characters: https://theasciicode.com.ar/