# Limit textarea field to Caps, numbers and the & symbol with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to limit a textarea field to Caps (A-Z), numbers (0-9) and this symbold (&).
Is this possible with jQuery?

this is my js:

```
$('#textarea').keyup(function(e){
    var keyed = $(this).val().replace(/[\n]/g,'<br />');
    $('#output').html(keyed);
});
```

Any help please? thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use Regular Expressions and provide your code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

Comment: works only with inputs, i need for textarea too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, I'd rather inform the user his input is not correct at validation time (form submition?) than just blocking it on keypress.

A function like this should work:

```
var test = function(chars){
  return /^([A-Z]|&|[0-9])*$/.test(chars);
}
$("input").change(function(){
  if(!test($(this).val()){
    //Do what you want
  }
});
```

**textareas should work the same way.**