# Restrict input for some characters through HTML onkeypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to restrict user's input if user is trying to type some characters (like space). To do so I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery) post.

But I wanted to make it through HTML's onkeypress attribute. And faced with problem, that if I specify function to return false, then nothing will happen, but if I return false right in HTML's attribute - input won't happen.

I can't understand what am I doing wrong. Can you please tell me how to solve this?

```js
function doMatch() {
  return false;  
}

$('#test').keypress(function() {
  //return false;   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="doMatch();" id="test"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

> But I wanted to make it through HTML's onkeypress attribute.

I recommend you to not do that, since it's better to keep the Javascript behavior out of your HTML code. The name os this technique is [*Unobstrusive Javascript*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

But if you really want to do that, you must use the `return` keyword to make it work:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return doMatch();" id="test"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add return before doMatch();

```js
function doMatch() {
  return false;  
}

$('#test').keypress(function() {
  //return false;   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" onkeypress="return doMatch();" id="test"/>
```