# Javascript, convert inline html js to normal js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have this **input** tag:

```
<input ... onkeypress="return /^[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$/.test(event.key)" id="id_title">
```

And I want it to accept only numbers, letters and spaces. I wonder how to rewrite it in my JS file with jQuery in modern JS version, because all methods from the Internet with old JS are crossed out. Like in here, https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/allow+only+letters+in+input+javascript **onkeypress** or **keyCode** methods are not working now. They are crossed out.

```
$('#id_title').on('keydown', function() {  

     let regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$/ // accepts only letters, numbers and spaces
     ... // how to continue?

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('#id_title').on('input', function(event) {  
    let regex = /^[A-Za-z0-9 -]*$/;
    return regex.test(event.key);
});
```

Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on the `test` method!

Comment: Hmm, okay, will it prevent the user for inputting for example "="?

Comment: Umm actually, it doesn't preserver the user from inputting it :/

Comment: change `input` to `keydown` or `keypress`, that's what `onkeypress` is

Comment: Yarin_007, yeah thanks, but why input doesn't work here?

Comment: `event.key` is undefined. Instead of `.on('input')`, you need `.on('keypress')`. But even that won't prevent a user from *pasting* an invalid character. For better answers to OP, see [How do I block or restrict special characters from input fields with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/895659/how-do-i-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-input-fields-with-jquery)